# xpath queries to find closest element

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, didselectrowatindexpath, domxpath, xpathnavigator

I am working on project with java and selenium webdriver 2.44, we need the closest element of text. For example I have email text on page and i need the closest element that is text box. I have run the below given xpath query on facebook.com. However, it finds numbers of input type that is email and text. We do not need jQuery to run as we are using selenium webdriver.

```
.//*[contains(text(),'Email')]/following::input[@type='email' or @type='text']
```

Can anyone provide me xpath query to find closest element on page. Or a tutorial site where I can learn how to query.
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28322015/what-will-be-the-best-way-to-select-drop-down-item-in-dojo-based-html-in-java-w/28324057#28324057

Comment: explain ` we need the closest element of text` . Are you looking for a  specific one?

Comment: yes, we need the textbox which is displayed under email or phone text, that is the closest text box. Text will be passed in parameter and which will search on page and will return the closest text box to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a perfect solution, though in facebook scenario u can find first element as:

```
(.//*[contains(text(),'Email')]/following::input[@type='email' or @type='text'])[1]
```

Another thing to add if you are getting multiple elements for your query you can use:

```
List<WebElement> txtList = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
txtList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[contains(text(),'Email')]/following::input[@type='email' or @type='text']"));
```

and use `txtList.get(0).sendKeys("abcd");`

Comment: Hi Vivek, thanks for your response. I have run the query and it has return two text, one that is displayed below the email or phone text and other is displayed from sign up section. Well, it has reduce the number of text box count, but still we required only one text box that is given below the email or phone text.

Comment: Is it? In firepath its showing only `1 matching node`. Can you please recheck it in firepath?

Comment: it is working thanks, also can you suggest me to tutorial site where I can learn how to query xpath

Comment: for drop down: .//*[contains(text(),'Gender')]/following::select[1]